# Get new tweet where I am a following, using API1.1 and twitterizer 2.4.3

Tags: c#, twitter

I extract tweets created by me like this:

```
OAuthTokens tokens = (OAuthTokens)context.Session["OAuthTokens"];
string username ="my_name";
string APIBaseAddress = 
"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?     
                              screen_name=" + username+"&count=50";
Uri Uri = new Uri(APIBaseAddress);
WebRequestBuilder requestBuilder = 
                  new WebRequestBuilder(Uri, HTTPVerb.GET, tokens);
using (HttpWebResponse response = requestBuilder.ExecuteRequest())
     {
     System.IO.StreamReader rdr = new
                       System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
     dynamic jSon = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rdr.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

How to get new tweets of people I am following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using this url:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?count=50
```

instead of APIBaseAddress